# Every k- cell is compact (Walter Rudin)

Tags: real-analysis

In the proof $I$ is a $k$-cell whose coordinates are bounded by $a_{j}\le x_{j}\le b_{j}$ where $1\le j\le k$.

From the proof: Suppose, to get a contradiction, that there exists an open cover $\{G_{\alpha}\}$ which has no finite subcover of $I$.

Put $c_{j}=(a_{j}+b_{j})/2$.  The intervals $[a_{j},c_{j}]$ and $[c_{j},b_{j}]$ then determine $2^{k}$ $k$-cells $Q_{i}$ whose union is $I$.

One of these $Q_i$, call it $I_1$, will also have no finite subcover.  Continuing this process we obtain a sequence $I_n$ with the following properties:

1. $I_n \subset I_{n-1}$ for all $n$.
2. $I_n$ is not covered by any finite subcollection of $\{ G_{\alpha}\}$.
3. If $x,y \in I_n$, the $|x-y| \leq 2^{-n}\delta$

By the definition of sequence $\{I_n\}$, (1) is satisfied

My question is:  How to prove that $\{I_n\}$ satisfies the (2) and (3) properties?

Please help me to clear my doubts.

Comment: Let $\delta$ be the maximum distance between two points in $I_1$. Then, (3) is automatically satisfied since the scale of $I_n$ is halved for each division. (2) is just an assumption to make a contradiction. If there's no finite subcollection of open covers for $I_n$, then, there should be $I_{n+1}$ where there's also no finite subcollection of open covers for it. If you continue this process, you will eventually reach at the contradiction.

Comment: @Aran :How to prove if $I_1$ is covered by finite subcollection of $\{ G_{\alpha} \}$, then I is covered by finite subcollection.I think if  $I_1 \subseteq \cup_{i=i}^n G_{\alpha _i}$, then $I \subseteq \cup_{i=1}^n G_{\alpha_i} \cup \{I-I_1\} $.I realy could not proceed

Comment: Why prove it from first principles? Show that $I = [0, 1]$ is compact (e.g., as a closed, bounded subspace of $\mathbb{R}$), then use Tychonoff's theorem (or the much eaiser to prove version for finite products).

Comment: I think it  is  not well-written, in that a neophyte may very readily not understand it. Especially "Continuing this process...". A student may ask "What process?" ....Illustrating the difficulty of teaching. Students may have difficulties that the teacher didn't expect.

Comment: @anomaly . Pedagogically better, I think, to just prove that any finite product of compact spaces is compact, than  to focus on $k$-cells.

Answer (score 2):

For (2), each set $I_n$ is chosen specifically so that it has no finite subcover. Indeed, by our assumption that $\{G_\alpha\}$ has no finite subcover, upon dividing $I$ into $2^k$ cells $Q_i$, it must be the case that at least one of these $Q_i$, call it $I_1$, has no finite subcover.

Now suppose we divide $I_1$ into $2^k$ cells $R_j$. It must also be the case that at least one of these $R_j$, call it $I_2$, has no finite subcover, otherwise each $R_j$ is covered by finitely many $G_\alpha$, whereby $I_1$ is covered by finitely many $G_\alpha$, contradicting what we have deduced that $I_1$ has no finite subcover.

Proceeding in this manner, we deduce that each $I_n$ has no finite subcover, which gives us (2).

To prove (3), recall the definition of $\delta$ as the diameter of the set $I$:
$$
\delta = \sup_{x,y\in I}|x-y| = \bigg(\sum_{j=1}^k(b_j-a_j)^2\bigg)^{1/2}.
$$
Now, $I_1$ has half the diameter of $I$ since $I_1$ is one of the cells obtained from $I$ by dividing each edge of $I$ in half. Thus $\operatorname{diameter}(I_1) = 2^{-1}\delta$. Likewise, $I_2$ has half the diameter of $I_1$, so that $\operatorname{diameter}(I_2) = 2^{-1}\operatorname{diameter}(I_1) = 2^{-2}\delta$. Proceeding in this manner, if $n\ge 1$, we deduce that $\operatorname{diameter}(I_n) = 2^{-n}\delta$.

By definition of the supremum, if $x,y\in I_n$, then
$$
|x-y|\le\sup_{x,y\in I_n}|x-y| = \operatorname{diameter}(I_n) = 2^{-n}\delta,
$$
which finally gives us (3).

Answer (score 0):

If $I$ is not compact,there exists at least one $Q_i$ which cannot be covered by a finite subcollection of ${G_\alpha}$. Otherwise the set $I$ will be covered by a union of $2^k$ finite subcollections which is also a finite subcover,that shows $I$ is compact.

So we can choose that $Q_i$ as the $I_1$.

Comment: This resolves property (2) in the Question, but does not address property (3). Since property (3) involves the factor $\delta$ that is not defined in the Question, some assumption has to be made about its meaning. One such assumption would be $\delta = \sum |b_i−a_i|$.